# How to break all the nested loops? (Python)

Tags: python, loops

Many times happened to me that I was coding 3 or 4 nested loops, the problem is that with the `break` statement, I could only skip one of the loops and the rest of those would continue to proceed...

Is there anyway to break all of the nested loops?

ex:

```
a = 3
b = 4
c = 5
while a <= 333:
    b = a + 1
    while  b <= 500:
        c = 1000 - a - b
        while c < 500:
            if c**2 == (a**2) + (b**2) and a + b + c = 1000:
                print("this is the first number : ", a)
                print("this is the second number : " ,b)
                print("and this is the third number : " ,c)
                break
            else :
                c +=1
        b +=1  
    a +=1
    print(a)
```

It's the code I have written for Project Euler #9!

> https://projecteuler.net/problem=9

when the condition of if statement is met... how can I stop those while loops from running?

Comment: You could try adding a boolean variable to all the while loops and setting it to false when you need to

Answer (score 3):

try create a function, and use `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to break out of nested loops with one `break` statement in python.